# Hibernate 6.4: Connection handling logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

We're trying to troubleshoot a DB connection handling issue (possible leak).
For this reason we'd like to configure logging of Hibernate to produce events covering opening & closing DB connections.

After some search & tests it appears that `org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl` is the most suitable source of such log events, however it currently logs only the "close connection" events - nothing about opening a connection.
See for example https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.4.4/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/resource/jdbc/internal/LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java#L256 (and line 263).

We tried to look at other classes in the `org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal` package, but none of them appears to log such information either.

I remember that in the past (older Hibernate versions) we were able to configure the logging to cover both types of operations.

Is that an oversight, or is there any reason why no "open connection" events are logged?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this just before attempting to obtain the connection to mark the start of the acquisition process :   (line 109)

```
if ( physicalConnection == null ) {

observer.jdbcConnectionAcquisitionStart();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to help here. It appears to ultimately point to a method in JdbcObserverImpl that does nothing and moreover the whole JdbcObserver is now deprecated and marked for future removal.